# Pagination in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm wondering if there is a helper (or a quick and dirty way) to show on the website how the page will print. Basically - only show print-only stylesheets **AND** pagination (i.e. where each page would start/stop).

Preferably, this would be done with raw JS; not a library.

Thanks!

Comment: Would you be okay with a browser extension, for instance web developer for firefox will let you view print css. More info: http://neutroncreations.com/blog/easy-print-css-coding-using-firebug-and-web-developer-toolbar/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is possible with standard browser javascript. You'd need some kind of browser extension that exposed an interface to a printer driver. My quick search I didn't find any, but that doesn't mean there isn't one out there.